# Getting the inverse of a matrix with matrix elements

Tags: matrices, inverse, newton-raphson, jacobian

I am solving a problem regarding newton's method.
We are using this as the function:
 [click to see function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/254xD.png)

Thus these are the Jacobian Matrix and the set up for Newton's Method:
[click here to see Jacobian and set up for Newton's Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL08I.png)

We are asked to get the inverse of the Jacobian using Gaussian Elimination and I know using Gaussian Elimination that would be JJ^-1 = I

My main question:
is what is the identity matrix to use given that J is a matrix that has matrix elements?
I'm thinking that if J is 2 x 2 and its matrix elements all have 2x2 sizes using the common 2x2 identity won't work. because an element of the matrix can never be a scalar since each element is 2x2.

or am I missing something?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The Jacobian matrix does not have matrices as elements. It is simply a large matrix with real numbers as elements, and the notation used there is merely a shorthand way of describing various regions of that larger matrix.